# Getting keyboard input to a control based on a WPF Grid (System.Windows.Controls.Grid)

Tags: c#, wpf, grid-layout

I have created a control that inherits from the WPF System.Windows.Controls.Grid.

I would like it to respond to key presses, but it doesn't.

It responds to Mouse input fine.

This is my constructor in part:

```cs
public ChDynamicGridProgrammer() : base()
{
    MouseLeftButtonDown += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_MouseLeftButtonDown_EventHandler;
    MouseMove += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_MouseMove;
    MouseRightButtonUp += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_MouseRightButtonUp;

    KeyDown += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_KeyDown;
}
```

I have also tried to bind a key to a command on my parent UserControl, this works but only when another control has focus.

I'm guessing this is a focus related issue and the Grid doesn't get focus, but I could do with some help getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the parent window's `PreviewKeyDown` event to handle all key presses in the window:

```
public class ChDynamicGridProgrammer : Grid
{
    public ChDynamicGridProgrammer() : base()
    {
        ...
        Loaded += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_Loaded;
    }

    private void ChDynamicGridProgrammer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= ChDynamicGridProgrammer_Loaded;
        Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
        window.PreviewKeyDown += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_KeyDown;
    }

    private void ChDynamicGridProgrammer_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("key pressed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Window.GetWindow(this) is a useful function I didn't know about.

Comment: Would this method steal the keyboard input from other controls on the form?

Comment: @Lance: No, other controls can still handle the same event just like before.

Comment: happily, I thought you upvoted answers, i didn't know to upvote a response with something that you found useful within until I read the text that pops when you hover over the upvote! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting `Focusable = true` and attaching to the Preview Events.

```
    public ChDynamicGridProgrammer() : base()
    {
        Focusable = true;

        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_MouseLeftButtonDown_EventHandler;
        PreviewMouseMove += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_MouseMove;
        PreviewMouseRightButtonUp += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_MouseRightButtonUp;

        PreviewKeyDown += ChDynamicGridProgrammer_PreviewKeyDown;
        
    }
```